# IIs can not load Css files in DNN

Tags: css, iis

Today I opened my browser to work on my local portal , but IIS con not be load CSS files.
Can you help me?
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Either this is a code side error, either a configuration side one.

You should check your browser console to see where he's looking for CSS files. By the way, check if the windows authentication is enabled in your web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this problem relation to web.config, because I never change web.config file, and last night I can work my portal , but last day when I opened my Dotnetnuke local portal, any css can not be load. I think this problem return to IIS . not do?

My portal shows such as:

```
Register
```

Login
My Website
en-USfa-IR

```
Getting Startedd
    Introduction With Dnn
    » Whats CMS
    » Whats DotNetNuke
    » DotNetNuke History
    DotNetNuke Reviews
    » DotNetNuke Feathers
    » DotNetNuke Resources
    » DotNetNuke Elements
    DotNetNuke Tools
    » DotNetNuke Modules
    » DotNetNuke Skins
    DotNetNuke Development
    » Module Programming
    » Skin Desing
Home
New Editor
    ERIS
    » child
About Us
Social
    MyProfile
    Users
    Groups
Test ImageGallery Page
```

ImageGallery
This is sample